# How to make a function on a web page, that edits strings in text files?

Tags: c#, blazor

With Blazor I've made a Blazor Server App, where there is a page that can upload txt files.
The files are then stored in the \wwwroot directory.
Now i'm trying to find out how to get some edit function on the page,
so the strings can be edited from there.

Here is some code that shows I want every 3 in my txt file replaced.

```
@code
{
    public void editFile()
    {
        File.WriteAllText(@"\wwwroot\DEJLIGER.txt", Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(@"\wwwroot\DEJLIGER.txt"), "3", "replacementString"));
    
    }
}
```

I'm just not sure how I can get the an edit function on the page that can replace the strings in a file.

Comment: FYI, It's best not store uploaded files anywhere that makes them publicly accessible! Anyone could override any legitimate files that you have or use the site to host their own files!

Comment: Yes I'm just storing them there for now, but thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are working on a hobby project, otherwise this is not a very good approach to store user data.

Under that assumption, this example probably helps you out:

```
<textarea @bind="_contents"></textarea>
<button @onclick="OpenFile">Open file</button>
<button @onclick="SaveFile">Save file</button>

@code
{
    string _contents { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    void OpenFile()
    {
        _contents = File.ReadAllText(@"\wwwroot\DEJLIGER.txt");
    }

    void SaveFile()
    {
        File.WriteAllText(@"\wwwroot\DEJLIGER.txt", _contents);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and no worry, the files are just temporarily stored there.